# Main column not rendering even with side column

Tags: html, css

I have a two column layout the main content area renders down the page. Not even with aside. I wonder if I need a wrapper div?
or maybe my CSS not right?
I did not post of the CSS just what Thought maybe important

[image]

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
 font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 background: #FFF;
    background-image:url(../assets/bg1.png);
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #000;
}
.sidebar h4 {
 padding-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 7px 7px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #A31923;
   background-color: #DE2D3A;
}
/* ~~this fixed width container surrounds the other divs~~ */
/*#container {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 padding: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 5px #CCCCCC;
 background-color: #fff;
}*/
.container {
 width: 1260px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #B8B8B8;
 /*margin: 0 auto;  the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
}

.sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.sidebar h4 {
 padding-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 7px 7px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #A31923;
   background-color: #DE2D3A;
}

.footer {
 padding: 10px 0;
 background: #CCC49F;
 position: relative;
 clear: both;
}


.fltrt { 
 float: right;
 margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { 
 float: left;
 margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { 
 clear:both;
 height:0;
 font-size: 1px;
 line-height: 0px;
}
.clear {
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
   <header>
  <h2>our website slogan here with header image</h2>
 </header>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li>X</li>
   <li>X</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <aside class="sidebar">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <h4>X</h4>
    <ul>
     <li>X</li>
     <li>X</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
 </aside>
 <main>
  <section>
  <article>
   <h2>CCCC</h2>
   <p>CCC</p>
  </article>
  <article>
   <h1>xXX<h1>
   <h2>XXX</h2>
   <p>XX</p>
  </article>
  <article>
   <h2>XXX</h2>
   <p>V</p>
  </article>
  </section>
 </main>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <footer>
  <p>XXX.</p>
 </footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `<aside>` tag does not do what you think it does. Check this article out: http://html5doctor.com/understanding-aside/

Comment: Thank you Michael, I read the article very enlightening cleared things up for me. I found this article that is pretty good too http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_aside_tag.cfm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder if I need a wrapper div?

Not really, you can achieve it without an additional wrapper.

> or maybe my CSS not right?

That is the question, your CSS could be much better. You are using `float`, and unless there is a good reason behind its use, we are on 2017: use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) instead and forget float elements for a time.

Your example hasn't the full code, so I will do a simple code snippet with a full width header, a 180px aside with the main content next to it, and a full width footer. All of this within only one wrapper: the `.container` element.

```css
span{
display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

header{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

aside{
  flex-basis: 180px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}

main{
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #f39c12;
}

footer{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <span>Header</span>
    <!-- Put your content here -->
  </header>
  
  <aside>
    <span>Aside</span>
    <!-- Put your content here -->
  </aside>
  
  <main>
    <span>Main</span>
    <!-- Put your content here -->
  </main>
  
  <footer>
    <span>Footer</span>
    <!-- Put your content here -->
  </footer>
</div>
```